# Send a larger number of emails with Laravel app

Tags: php, email, laravel, mailchimp

I am currently developing an application in PHP using the Laravel framework. I'm new to Laravel. In this application I will need to send survey-links to a larger amount of email addresses (everything from 5 to about 1000 recipients or more).

I have never worked with mass emailing before. I guess that just using built in email functions could get my server flagged for sending spam and even get me suspended. It's important that all emails reach the recipients and that they do so at least the same day.

I don't need any scheduler. I only need a function that I can feed an email to and it gets delivered. When my application invites a number of recipients to answer a survey, every email contains an individual link for the survey, that identifies the user. So it **must be able to send a large amount of individual emails.**

Should I use something built in to in Laravel or go for *Mailchimp*, *Mandrill* or some other external service.

What's your experience?

Comment: Mandrill works fine with the API built into laravel, but they won't let you send more than about 400 emails per hour at the start. They measure the open rate of your sent mails and will rate you with a reputation class resulting of this open rate (might be more criterias). So, you won't enjoy sending a large amount of emails for a long time as your rate when sending 1000 survey links (most likely) won't be too good.

Comment: I think the open rate will be pretty good. This is mostly for companies doing internal surveys. I'm building it for a company that works with surveys. Will Mandrill queue emails if the number of outgoing mails are to large?

Comment: I'm not well aware of their queueing, but for queueing purposes you can go locally with beanstalkd or as a service with [iron.io] (http://www.iron.io/). I like beanstalkd

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you use an external SMTP such as Sendgrid https://sendgrid.com/. It's really easy to setup and if you have control over your server environment, I recommend installing a Postfix mail server and configuring it to send all email via Sendgrid. Instructions for that are here:
https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Mail_Servers/postfix.html

Installing your own local mail server allows you to very quickly add bulk email to your mail queue then your local mail server can deal with all the connection issues, retries, etc...

I used this setup in my email marketing setup and can send 15000 emails in 15mins.

Another advantage to using Sendgrid (any probably other email services) is that they can handle unsubscribes and provide a feedback loop for users who mark spam, so your application doesn't have to.

Answer (score -1):

I personally use Amazon SQS to queue the mail using Laravels Mail Queue functionality which the Laravel queue listener processes and pipes to Amazon SES to deliver. I mail out 12,000 mails twice a month and this approach works well. ( sorry if when you said you don't want to use a scheduler this it what you meant! )